# IndexChangedEvent property not being received correctly

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

This one is really confusing me.  I'm dispatching an `IndexChangedEvent` that I've created myself, setting the `oldIndex` and `newIndex` properties before dispatching.  When the event is received in the appropriate handler, the `oldIndex` and `newIndex` values are received as -1, even though I've verified them (using `Alert.show()`) to be the correct value before being sent.

I'm creating it like this:

```
var myEvent:IndexChangedEvent = new IndexChangedEvent(IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT, false, false, null, 3, 2);
```

The `3,2` parameters are just ones that I'm using for debugging, and they should (and I've verified that they do) set the `oldIndex` and `newIndex` properties of the IndexChangedEvent.  I then immediately dispatch the event like so:

```
dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

The handler is set up as follows:

```
report.addEventListener(IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT, shiftHandler);
```

And here is the handler code:

```
private function shiftHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void {
    if (event.oldIndex == -1 || event.newIndex == -1) {
        Alert.show("-1 index received");
    }
}
```

To help ensure that I am not crazy, this is my ACTUAL code before dispatching the event:

```
var myEvent:IndexChangedEvent = new IndexChangedEvent(IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT, false, false, null, 3, 2);
Alert.show(myEvent.oldIndex + " : " + myEvent.newIndex);
dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

Every time I shift a header (which fires the event), I get 2 Alert boxes, one that shows `3 : 2` and another that shows `-1 index received`.  It's driving me crazy.  Can someone let me know why my event's properties aren't being persisted across a dispatch?

Comment: Show us the code of your custom `IndexChangedEvent`.

Comment: @RIAstar, it's not a custom event, it's a [built-in flex event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/IndexChangedEvent.html). When I said I've created it myself, I just mean that I created it via its constructor (as shown above), sorry.

Comment: Aha, I was gonna ask you why you didn't use the built-in event ;) Are you absolutely certain that the event being dispatched and the one being received are the same instance? You can verify this by looking at their memory addresses in FlashBuilder's debugger view. Also, I suppose you have a custom header class then. Perhaps the event is being caught and redispatched somewhere in the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a hunch, but it sounds to me as if you're dispatching the `IndexChangedEvent` from somewhere else, perhaps another listener in your code. If you have a look at the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/IndexChangedEvent.html) for the event, the default values for the `oldIndex` and `newIndex` properties are both -1 so something like the following would result in the erroneous event you receive:

```
dispatchEvent(new IndexChangedEvent(IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT));
```

Have you tried searching your code base for references to `IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT`?

Comment: I am using other internal swc libraries, so this might be it actually.  I'll try creating my own custom event to test this out (Thank you for the update too).

Comment: That was my mistake, corrected now. Based on your description of the issue, I'm almost certain that the same event is being dispatched twice, possibly as a result of the action which results in you dispatching the event manually. Is it possible that the Flex framework is dispatching the event as a result of that action?

Comment: You were correct.  A library I was using was (very stupidly) catching the event and redispatching it as a `new IndexChangedEvent('headerShift')` (yup, didn't even use the HEADER_SHIFT constant).  Thanks!!